# How to show a WinJS AppBar when a page fragment loads?

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs, appbar

I'd like to show the AppBar when a page fragment loads, but this code running in the ready function isn't working as expected:

```
function ready(element, options) {
    var appBar = document.getElementById("appBar").winControl;
    appBar.disabled = false;
    appBar.show();
}
```

How do I show the AppBar when the page fragment loads?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are creating the appbar correctly in the HTML file.

Then, in the `ready` method, you should first call

```
WinJS.UI.processAll(elements)
        .then(function () {
              var appbar = document.getElementById("appBar");
              if (appbar) {
                  appbar.winControl.show();
              }
         });
```

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh440975.aspx), `processAll` function "applies declarative control binding to all elements, starting at the specified root element." (i.e. turning all the html element into WinJS controls)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following piece of code:

```
document.getElementById("appBar").winControl.show()
```

And it works as expected(app bar is shown on page load).

The same way also used at the msdn sample:
[App bar sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-bar-sample-a57eeae9)

It seems that you have another problem(invalid controls on app bar or something else).

Could you please provide more details or even app sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you get null error call WinJS.UI.processAll() in your initialization code.

```
WinJS.UI.processAll();
appBar.winControl.show();
```

HTML

```
<div id="appBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{placement:'bottom'}">
```